# Creating a calculated table by passing a measure or parameter

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a requirement where I have a data like this,

```
Date      Name  Age 
1-1-2018  A     1
2-2-2018  B     1
3-3-2018  B     1
6-6-2018  C     2
7-7-2018  B     6
```

I am trying to give a slicer to the user to select the required number of months from the last month.

So to do that, I am using a calculated column like this:

```
Month Year = DATEDIFF((Table1[Date]), TODAY(), MONTH) + 1
```

So that changes the data to something like this:

```
Date      Name  Age  MonthYear
1-1-2018  A     1    7
2-2-2018  B     1    6
3-3-2018  B     1    5
6-6-2018  C     2    2
7-7-2018  B     6    1
```

The user selects the Month Year from the Slicer.

For example, when he selects 2, I want to display the last 2 months records in the table.

Expected Output:

```
Date      Name  Age  
6-6-2018  C     2   
7-7-2018  B     6
```

This works for me if I hardcode it like this:

```
Calculated Table = CALCULATETABLE(Table1,
                       FILTER(Table1, OR(Table1[MonthYear] > 2, Table1[MonthYear] = 2)))
```

But it fails when I try to pass the value in the place of 2 dynamically through a measure using `SelectedValue` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculated columns and calculated tables cannot reference a slicer value since they are only computed when you load your data.

If you want to apply this filtering to a visual, I'd suggest creating a separate table for your slicer. For example, you could use `Months = GENERATESERIES(1,12)` and then rename the column `Months` as well.

Use the `Months[Months]` column for your slicer and then create a measure which references it to filter your table/matrix visual.

```
Filter = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(Months[Months]) >= MAX(Table1[Month Year]), 1, 0)
```

Then use that measure in your Visual level filters box:

[image: Output]